# Reading pixels in python: "ValueError too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, runtime-error, pixel, radial

I want to read a .tif file and count the number of pixels in an image and determine the density of objects, but when I attempt this `y, x = np.indices(image.shape)` it gives me then

```
Value Error (ValueError: too many values to unpack, File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>).
```

My code is as follows:

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

#Function
def radial_plot(image):
    y, x = np.indices(image.shape) # <----- Problem here???
    center = np.array([(x.max()-x.min())/2.0, (x.max()-x.min())/2.0])
    r = np.hypot(x - center[0], y - center[1])
    ind = np.argsort(r.flat)- center[1])
    r_sorted = r.flat[ind]
    i_sorted = image.flat[ind]
    r_int = r_sorted.astype(int)
    deltar = r_int[1:] - r_int[:-1]
    rind = np.where(deltar)[0]
    nr = rind[1:] - rind[:-1]
    csim = np.cumsum(i_sorted, dtype=float)
    tbin = csim[rind[1:]] - csim[rind[:-1]]
    radial_prof = tbin / nr
    return rad
#Main
img = plt.imread('dat.tif')
radial_plot(img)
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Hi wnnmaw: I am using Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are attempting to assign more than two values to only two varibles:

```
>>> a, b = range(2)  #Assign two values to two variables
>>> a
0
>>> b
1   
>>> a, b = range(3)  #Attempt to assign three values to two variables
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

In Python 2.x you can do the following:

```
>>> a, b = range(3)[0], range(3)[1:]
>>> a
0
>>> b
[1, 2]
```

Just for completeness, if you had Python 3.x, you could do [Extended Iterable Unpacking](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
>>> a, *b, c = range(5)
>>> a
0
>>> c
4
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If this solved your issue, please mark it as the "accepted answer" so that others who have the same issue as you can quickly find the solution

Answer (score 0):

`np.indices` returns an array representing the indices of the grid. The error basically indicates that there are more than 2 values obtained by calling the `indices` method. Since it's returning a grid, you can assign it to a variable such as `grid` and then access the indices accordingly.

The crux of the error is the function call returns more than just 2 values, and in your code you are trying to 'squeeze' them into just 2 variables.

For eg.

```
s = "this is a random string"
x, y = s.split()
```

The above code gives you a value error since there are 5 strings obtained by calling `split()`, while I am trying to accommodate them into just 2 variables.